# How to prevent calling (click) method on selecting/highlighting text inside the element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular

I'm trying to add an option to highlight/select the text on a element of the list of items. But when I'm trying to do so it get's redirected to this item details by open() method like below.

```
<div *ngFor="let resource of resources">
    <mat-card (click)="open()">
        <span>text to select/highlight</span>
        ...some code
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

I have tried to add `(onselect)="$event.stopPropagation()"` like I'm using in other parts of the code to prevent such things for `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` but it's not working.

Am I using right directive or how I can achieve this?

Comment: I would just add a button inside the card and add the click event to it instead of the whole container, it leaves no need for work arounds.

Comment: The problem is that you want to prevent the propagation only if the user selects text and not on a simple click. The catch is that you basically select with a click (and drag inbetween). You would thne need a function that checks if text gets selected to determine weather you want to select text or call the open method. As mentioned above, that is usually a bad idea. The user experience gets kind of wobbly and it might not work always as intended. Create a button - or add a header/blank area that can get clicked - for the open method.